# Overwriting same values has any downside?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

There are 2 queries at below and actually both of them are doing exactly same thing. It marks all products as published. But first one seems overwriting even Published is 1 and seems doing more work. Is there any downside of first query compared to second one from performance, logs...etc perspective?

Published column is bit not null

```
UPDATE Products
SET Published = 1
```

Second query

```
UPDATE Products
SET Published = 1
WHERE Published != 1
```

Comment: A good question. I've often wondered the same thing, in a similar context.

Comment: There's going to be performance differences, but how much they matter and how significant they are depends on your indexes and the size of the tables.

Comment: Have you looked at the statistics output for both queries and compared reads/writes/execution plans? If it does more writes, it would objectively have a performance hit, but it might be negligible in terms of time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using these set of queries on a table that contains a huge amount of data with no index for the `Published` column? I believe the first query would be much more effective rather than the second query in those kind of scenario. The table I'm referring to has multiple columns as well with no index at all. Hope someone clarify this.